# EF Core DBContext targeting only part of the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to ask, if it is possible to target only one table with DbContext in Entity Framework Core?

In shortcut, I have a system that manages everything about database and all of the tables in it, but now I am writing new system, that uses the same database, but only needs one of the tables. Also I do not really need all the entities in method `OnModelCreating` etc...

Lets say I have something like:

```cs
        public virtual DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }        
        public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }        
        public virtual DbSet<AdminProject> AdminProjects { get; set; }        
        public virtual DbSet<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }        

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
           // something
        }        

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder for all of the tables
        }
```

but I would prefer simply just:

```cs
        public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

and later in `OnModelCreating` just model for Project entity.

Thank you for all your help

Comment: You can model only the tables you want, you don't need to include everything (just be mindful of foreign keys etc if you're inserting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your new project uses a **copy** of the original `DbContext` you can simply remove anything you don't need.

Unless you create a migration from the new context **this won't change your database**.

---

*It might be worth mentioning:* A code first approach, where the DB is generated based on your code, would typically be managed by a shared `DbContext` since you can't have multiple `__MigrationHistory` tables in a single Database.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mapping.
First create the model of the table you will use. Like

```
 public class Foo
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

After crate mapping class

```
 public class FooMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("FooTable");
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("nameofyourcolumninsqltable").IsRequired();;
            builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasColumnName("nameofyourcolumninsqltable");;
            builder.Property(c => c.Phone).HasColumnName("nameofyourcolumninsqltable");
        }
    }
```

Finally initialize in the DbContex

```
 public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context(DbContextOptions< Context > options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public Context()
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new FooMapping());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use db first approach of Entity Framework Core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "{Connection String}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t {TableName}
```

If you change {Connection String} with your connection string and {TableName} with your table name, it will create your table entity.